# Transfer variable from promise to promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Trying to push a variable within a promise to another

```
function initial_view(){
    var append_data = "";

    loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data).then(function() {
        $("#main-content").prepend(append_data);
    });
};

function loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data){
    return playerHeader().then(post_app_data => {
        append_data += post_app_data;
    });
};
```

The append_data is logging the data correctly within the return. I just don't know how to send it without making it a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `return` it out of the `then` handler in `loadViewFunctions`, and have the `then` handler on `loadViewFunction`'s promise accept it; see `***` commented lines:

```
function initial_view(){
    var append_data = "";

    loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data).then(function(updated_data) { // ***
        $("#main-content").prepend(updated_data); // ***
    });
}

function loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data){
    return playerHeader().then(post_app_data => {
        return append_data + post_app_data; // ***
    });
}
```

Alternately in this particular case, just do the appending within `initial_view`:

```
function initial_view(){
    var append_data = "";

    loadViewFunctions(view_functions).then(function(view_data) { // ***
        $("#main-content").prepend(append_data + view_data); // ***
    });
}

function loadViewFunctions(view_functions) { // ***
    return playerHeader();
}
```

*(I assume there's more to `loadViewFunctions` than in the question; otherwise, just use `playerHeader` in `initial_view`.)*

---

Side note: Function *declarations* (what you have above) don't need `;` after them. `;` is a *statement*-terminator, but declarations aren't statements.

Comment: Thanks guys, so noob... oops.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not returning a value from the `playerHeader().then()` callback.

```
function initial_view(){
    var append_data = "";

    loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data).then(function(modifiedAppendData) {
        $("#main-content").prepend(modifiedAppendData);
    });
};

function loadViewFunctions(view_functions,append_data){
    return playerHeader().then(post_app_data => {
        append_data += post_app_data;
        return append_data;
    });
};
```

Promises allow you to chain your `then`/`catch` calls, but they also allow you to modify your data between each one. What's happening in your original example is that your chronologically first `then` call is returning undefined, so that is what the 2nd `then` receives as an argument.